# Forcing a build when properties change in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have set up my build so that I can pass in a number as a build property:

```
msbuild MyProject.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:SomeNumber="123"
```

The MSBuild project generates a file and adds it via:

```
<Compile Include="$(SomeFileContainingSomeNumber)" />
```

This file is only generated if `SomeNumber` is specified.

When I change or omit the number and build a second time, the MSBuild projects do not get rebuilt with the new value. I believe this is because none of the project files have changed.

How can I set up my project so that changing the `SomeNumber` property triggers a rebuild?

Comment: Why not just specify what targets you want, e.g. `/t:"Clean;Build"`

Comment: I want to do incremental builds. I do not want to rebuild my entire solution or entire project when just a single C# file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using MSBuild 3.5. It seems that putting a `Condition` on a `BeforeBuild` `Target` interferes with its execution. When I moved the `Condition` from the `Target` to the individual actions within the target, I was able to get the desired behavior.

Using the following I was able to get MSBuild to compile properly every time, whether or not the `SomeNumber` property changed. The project may be rebuilding `SomeFile.cs` every time, whether or not its contents has changed, because its timestamp is changing.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SomeFile>SomeFile.cs</SomeFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="BeforeClean">
    <Delete Files="$(SomeFile)" />
</Target>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <WriteLinesToFile Condition="'$(SomeNumber)' == ''" File="$(SomeFile)" Lines="//" Overwrite="true" />
    <WriteLinesToFile Condition="'$(SomeNumber)' != ''" File="$(SomeFile)" Lines="$(SomeNumber)" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(SomeFile)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The `Lines="//"` is required because `WriteLinesToFile` will delete the file if you put nothing or whitespace there.

Comment: rather than write "//" to the file, you could look at the [Touch Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37fwbyt5.aspx)